# lxml: how to know what namespace to use for namespace prefix?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I've a XML in local drive, that I need to upload to a WebService.

The WebService says that `UBLVersionID` is missing, but I see this tag in the XML file.

I need to understand why it says it is missing when **the tag is in there**:

```
<cbc:UBLVersionID>2.0</cbc:UBLVersionID>
```

I made a python script to check if tag was present, if yes print it's text.

But I guess it has to do something with the namespace, because when I use:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml.etree import fromstring

tree = fromstring('''FULL XML''')
elem = tree.xpath('//cbc:UBLVersionID')
l = [e.text for e in elem]
print(l)
```

I get:

> lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Undefined namespace prefix

When removing: the namespace prefix:

Only doing: `elem = tree.xpath('//cbc:UBLVersionID')` I get an empty list.

**Original XML has encoding because sometimes tags texts contain spanish characters.**

**ORIGINAL XML:** You may need to remove encoding to test it.

However, don't know LXML is the right library for me as I'll have to work with encodings for spanish characters :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?><Invoice
xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2"
xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2"
xmlns:sac="urn:sunat:names:specification:ubl:peru:schema:xsd:SunatAggregateComponents-1"
xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <ext:UBLExtensions>
 <ext:UBLExtension>
 <ext:ExtensionContent>
 <sac:AdditionalInformation>
 <sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotal>
 <cbc:ID>1001</cbc:ID>
 <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="PEN">1407.29</cbc:PayableAmount>
 </sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotal>
 <sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotal>
 <cbc:ID>1004</cbc:ID>
 <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="PEN">48.00</cbc:PayableAmount>
 </sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotal>
 <sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotal>
 <cbc:ID>2005</cbc:ID>
 <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="PEN">74.07</cbc:PayableAmount>
 </sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotal>
 <sac:AdditionalProperty>
 <cbc:ID>1000</cbc:ID>
 <cbc:Value>SON MIL SEISCIENTOS SESENTA Y 60/100</cbc:Value>
 </sac:AdditionalProperty>
 </sac:AdditionalInformation>
 </ext:ExtensionContent>
 </ext:UBLExtension>
 <ext:UBLExtension><ext:ExtensionContent><ds:Signature
Id="signatureKG"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod
Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/><ds:SignatureMethod
Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference
URI=""><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform
Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#envelopedsignature"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod
Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>ld6X+TvM42Fe+F1KM/OB
jiKpnko=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>W6DbMHJEFmU7G
uiU0O+HRUqVzQZZW3QndYtUyeL0VxXuTafHu2vBC+OXvnnali43VXRGQ+/E0tPl
ZAssqI/PEPfzIU79Wufq6saxYGHKvzdnBi6hnaMuCSG5THHNFppx4aT1KNg7p/koBB3U8PT9C6m6
UnkJJNUquHkFc9BCqI8=</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509SubjectName>1.2
.840.113549.1.9.1=#161a4253554c434140534f55544845524e504552552e434f4d2e5045,CN=Carlos
Vega,OU=10200545523,O=Vega Poblete Carlos
Enrique,L=CHICLAYO,ST=LAMBAYEQUE,C=PE</ds:X509SubjectName><ds:X509Certificate>MIIESTCCAz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</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature><
/ext:ExtensionContent></ext:UBLExtension></ext:UBLExtensions>
<cbc:UBLVersionID>2.0</cbc:UBLVersionID>
<cbc:CustomizationID>1.0</cbc:CustomizationID>
<cbc:ID>BC01-3652</cbc:ID>
<cbc:IssueDate>2012-06-24</cbc:IssueDate>
<cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>03</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
<cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>PEN</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
<cac:Signature>
<cbc:ID>IDSignKG</cbc:ID>
<cac:SignatoryParty>
<cac:PartyIdentification>
<cbc:ID>10200545523</cbc:ID>
</cac:PartyIdentification>
<cac:PartyName>
<cbc:Name>VEGA POBLETE CARLOS ENRIQUE</cbc:Name>
</cac:PartyName>
</cac:SignatoryParty>
<cac:DigitalSignatureAttachment>
<cac:ExternalReference>
<cbc:URI>#SignatureKG</cbc:URI>
</cac:ExternalReference>
</cac:DigitalSignatureAttachment>
</cac:Signature>
<cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
<cbc:CustomerAssignedAccountID>10200545523</cbc:CustomerAssignedAccountID>
<cbc:AdditionalAccountID>6</cbc:AdditionalAccountID>
<cac:Party>
<cac:PartyName>
<cbc:Name>ELECTRODOMESTICOS CRUZ DE MOTUPE</cbc:Name>
</cac:PartyName>
<cac:PostalAddress>
<cbc:ID>140106</cbc:ID>
<cbc:StreetName>AV. LOS TALLANES #235</cbc:StreetName>
<cbc:CitySubdivisionName>URB. MIGUEL GRAU</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
<cbc:CityName>CHICLAYO</cbc:CityName>
<cbc:CountrySubentity>LAMBAYEQUE</cbc:CountrySubentity>
<cbc:District>LA VICTORIA</cbc:District>
<cac:Country>
<cbc:IdentificationCode>PE</cbc:IdentificationCode>
</cac:Country>
</cac:PostalAddress>
<cac:PartyLegalEntity>
<cbc:RegistrationName>VEGA POBLETE CARLOS ENRIQUE</cbc:RegistrationName>
</cac:PartyLegalEntity>
</cac:Party>
</cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
<cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
<cbc:CustomerAssignedAccountID>00078647</cbc:CustomerAssignedAccountID>
<cbc:AdditionalAccountID>1</cbc:AdditionalAccountID>
<cac:Party>
<cac:PartyLegalEntity>
<cbc:RegistrationName>SOLEDAD ASUNCION CARRASCO PEREZ</cbc:RegistrationName>
</cac:PartyLegalEntity>
</cac:Party>
</cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
<cac:TaxTotal>
<cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="PEN">253.31</cbc:TaxAmount>
<cac:TaxSubtotal>
<cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="PEN">253.31</cbc:TaxAmount>
<cac:TaxCategory>
<cac:TaxScheme>
<cbc:ID>1000</cbc:ID>
<cbc:Name>IGV</cbc:Name>
<cbc:TaxTypeCode>VAT</cbc:TaxTypeCode>
</cac:TaxScheme>
</cac:TaxCategory>
</cac:TaxSubtotal>
</cac:TaxTotal>
<cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
<cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="PEN">1660.60</cbc:PayableAmount>
</cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
<cac:InvoiceLine>
<cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
<cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="NIU">1</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
<cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="PEN">845.76</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
<cac:PricingReference>
<cac:AlternativeConditionPrice>
<cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="PEN">998.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
<cbc:PriceTypeCode>01</cbc:PriceTypeCode>
</cac:AlternativeConditionPrice>
</cac:PricingReference>
<cac:TaxTotal>
<cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="PEN">152.24</cbc:TaxAmount>
<cac:TaxSubtotal>
<cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="PEN">152.24</cbc:TaxAmount>
<cac:TaxCategory>
<cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>10</cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>
<cac:TaxScheme>
<cbc:ID>1000</cbc:ID>
<cbc:Name>IGV</cbc:Name>
<cbc:TaxTypeCode>VAT</cbc:TaxTypeCode>
</cac:TaxScheme>
</cac:TaxCategory>
</cac:TaxSubtotal>
</cac:TaxTotal>
<cac:Item>
<cbc:Description>Refrigeradora marca "AXM" no frost de 200 ltrs</cbc:Description>
<cac:SellersItemIdentification>
<cbc:ID>REF564</cbc:ID>
</cac:SellersItemIdentification>
</cac:Item>
<cac:Price>
<cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="PEN">845.76</cbc:PriceAmount>
</cac:Price>
</cac:InvoiceLine>
<cac:InvoiceLine>
<cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>
<cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="NIU">1</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
<cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="PEN">635.59</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
<cac:PricingReference>
<cac:AlternativeConditionPrice>
<cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="PEN">750.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
<cbc:PriceTypeCode>01</cbc:PriceTypeCode>
</cac:AlternativeConditionPrice>
</cac:PricingReference>
<cac:TaxTotal>
<cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="PEN">114.41</cbc:TaxAmount>
<cac:TaxSubtotal>
<cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="PEN">114.41</cbc:TaxAmount>
<cac:TaxCategory>
<cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>10</cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>
<cac:TaxScheme>
<cbc:ID>1000</cbc:ID>
<cbc:Name>IGV</cbc:Name>
<cbc:TaxTypeCode>VAT</cbc:TaxTypeCode>
</cac:TaxScheme>
</cac:TaxCategory>
</cac:TaxSubtotal>
</cac:TaxTotal>
<cac:Item>
<cbc:Description>Cocina a gas GLP, marca "AXM" de 5 hornillas</cbc:Description>
<cac:SellersItemIdentification>
<cbc:ID>COC124</cbc:ID>
</cac:SellersItemIdentification>
</cac:Item>
<cac:Price>
<cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="PEN">635.59</cbc:PriceAmount>
</cac:Price>
</cac:InvoiceLine>
<cac:InvoiceLine>
<cbc:ID>3</cbc:ID>
<cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="NIU">1</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
<cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="PEN">0.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
<cac:PricingReference>
<cac:AlternativeConditionPrice>
<cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="PEN">0.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
<cbc:PriceTypeCode>01</cbc:PriceTypeCode>
</cac:AlternativeConditionPrice>
<cac:AlternativeConditionPrice>
<cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="PEN">4.80</cbc:PriceAmount>
<cbc:PriceTypeCode>02</cbc:PriceTypeCode>
</cac:AlternativeConditionPrice>
</cac:PricingReference>
<cac:TaxTotal>
<cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="PEN">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
<cac:TaxSubtotal>
<cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="PEN">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
<cac:TaxCategory>
<cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>31</cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>
<cac:TaxScheme>
<cbc:ID>1000</cbc:ID>
<cbc:Name>IGV</cbc:Name>
<cbc:TaxTypeCode>VAT</cbc:TaxTypeCode>
</cac:TaxScheme>
</cac:TaxCategory>
</cac:TaxSubtotal>
</cac:TaxTotal>
<cac:Item>
<cbc:Description>Sixpack de gaseosa "Guaraná" de 400 ml.</cbc:Description>
<cac:SellersItemIdentification>
<cbc:ID>NOB012</cbc:ID>
</cac:SellersItemIdentification>
</cac:Item>
<cac:Price>
<cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="PEN">0.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
</cac:Price>
</cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

**Objective:**

1.- Check if <*cbc:UBLVersionID>2.0 exist.
2.- Extract and print it's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not correctly providing namespace information to the `xpath` method. You should read through the "[Namespaces and prefixes](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes)" section of the `lxml` documentation.

Instead of:

```
elem = tree.xpath('//cbc:UBLVersionID')
```

You want:

```
elem = tree.xpath('//cbc:UBLVersionID', namespaces={'cbc': 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2'})
```

Given your input data, this will set `elem` to a list containing a single element:

```
>>> elem = tree.xpath('//cbc:UBLVersionID', namespaces={'cbc': 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2'})
>>> elem
[<Element {urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2}UBLVersionID at 0x7f536f1c83c0>]
```

---

If you're going to be making many xpath queries against your data, you'll want to put your namespace mapping into a variable instead.  For example:

```
from lxml import etree

NSMAP = {
    "default": "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2",
    "cac": "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2",
    "cbc": "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2",
    "ccts": "urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2",
    "ds": "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#",
    "ext": "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2",
    "qdt": "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2",
    "sac": "urn:sunat:names:specification:ubl:peru:schema:xsd:SunatAggregateComponents-1",
    "udt": "urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2",
    "xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
}

with open('data.xml') as fd:
    tree = etree.parse(fd)

elem = tree.xpath('//cbc:UBLVersionID', namespaces=NSMAP)
```

Comment: Ty, I'll try this, but **how did you know to use those `namespaces`?** don't find them in documentation.

Comment: Those namespaces are right there in the sample data you posted. They are attached to the opening `<Invoice>` element.